# Join and display information from two tables

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have two tables:

1. `category`

   ```
   +----+------+
   | ID | Name |
   +----+------+
   |  1 | news |
   |  2 | blog |
   +----+------+
   ```
2. `articles`

   ```
   +----+----------+---------------+
   | ID | category |     title     |
   +----+----------+---------------+
   |  1 |        1 | hello         |
   |  2 |        2 | yamen         |
   |  3 |        2 | stackoverflow |
   |  4 |        1 | nice day      |
   +----+----------+---------------+
   ```

Now I need to display each category name together with the total number of articles inside it.

Comment: Have you Googled "MySQL joins" or "define:desplay"?

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to join your tables and group the results using an appropriate aggregate function:

```sql
SELECT   category.name, COUNT(articles.ID)
FROM     category LEFT JOIN articles ON articles.category = category.ID
GROUP BY category.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 Select c.ID,  
 c.category, 
 count(a.title) as titlecount, 
 GROUP_CONCAT(a.title SEPARATOR ',') as titles
 FROM category c
 INNER JOIN article a on c.ID = a.category
 group by c.ID
```